# Listview selector wrong background

Tags: android, listview, colors, background

at API7 there I have the problem that if I select a row the background changes and not my selected row. Where is my mistake?
With my phone with Android 4 there is no problem with the color, whats wrong?

list_selector_flatcolor.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/list_row_default_bg" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/list_row_pressed_bg" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/list_row_selected_bg" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

Layout with listview:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/custom_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_flatcolor"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

colors.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="text_color_default">#00000C</color>
    <color name="text_color_inverse">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="list_row_default_bg">#ffd30210</color>
    <color name="list_row_pressed_bg">#008cef</color>
    <color name="list_row_selected_bg">#86d3f6</color>
</resources>
```

[image]

Comment: Try to use `state_activated` for your `row_selector`.

Comment: still doesn't work. For what I have to use state_activated ?

Comment: from my new code or from the smartphone ?

Comment: added the picture and changed the list_selector_flatcolor.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `selector.xml`. You need to add `android:state_selected` state.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
 android:state_pressed="true" 
 android:drawable="@color/list_row_pressed_bg" />
<item 
 android:state_selected="true" 
 android:drawable="@color/list_row_selected_bg" />
<item 
 android:drawable="@color/list_row_default_bg" />
```

And if you are used `Custom Adapter` then you can set this selector as a `Background` to your `Custom Layout` like:

```
android:background="@drawable/selector"
```

Comment: thanks android:background="@drawable/item_selector" I forgot this :)

Comment: how can I do that the selected row takes the right color and just if i select an other one then the color changes?

Comment: @For more information go to official docs http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html). there are many states available .you can set state with your color.